# Error ORA-00210 while starting database Oracle?

Tags: oracle

While starting up oracle using following command i get following error:

```
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  288141312 bytes
Fixed Size                  2252504 bytes
Variable Size             230687016 bytes
Database Buffers           50331648 bytes
Redo Buffers                4870144 bytes
ORA-00205: error in identifying control file, check alert log for more info
```

When i check alert logs, i see following message:

```
Wed Nov 02 05:45:35 2016
ALTER DATABASE   MOUNT
ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
ORA-00202: control file: '/optware/oracle/11.2.0.4/db_1/dbs/<sid>_control2'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
ORA-00210: cannot open the specified control file
ORA-00202: control file: '/optware/oracle/11.2.0.4/db_1/dbs/<sid>_control1'
ORA-27037: unable to obtain file status
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 3
```

However when i check list of control files, i see location but dont know why file for control were not created:

```
SQL> show parameter CONTROL_FILES 

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
control_files                        string      /optware/oracle/11.2.0.4/db_1/
                                                 dbs/<sid>_control1, /optwar
                                                 e/oracle/11.2.0.4/db_1/dbs/<sid>_control2
```

DB Creation script:

```
CREATE DATABASE "mydb"
MAXINSTANCES 8
MAXLOGHISTORY 1
MAXLOGFILES 16
MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
MAXDATAFILES 100
DATAFILE '/optware/oradata/mydb/system.dbf' SIZE 1024M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  10240K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL
SYSAUX DATAFILE '/optware/oradata/mydb/sysaux.dbf' SIZE 1024M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  10240K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
SMALLFILE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE '/optware/oradata/mydb/temp.dbf' SIZE 1500M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  640K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
SMALLFILE UNDO TABLESPACE "UNDOTB_mydb" DATAFILE '/optware/oradata/mydb/undotbs2.dbf' SIZE 500M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT  5120K MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
NATIONAL CHARACTER SET UTF8
LOGFILE GROUP 1 ('/optware/oradata/mydb/redo1_a1.rdo', '/optware/oradata/mydb/redo1_b1.rdo') SIZE 20M,
GROUP 2 ('/optware/oradata/mydb/redo1_a2.rdo', '/optware/oradata/mydb/redo1_b2.rdo') SIZE 20M,
GROUP 3 ('/optware/oradata/mydb/redo1_a3.rdo', '/optware/oradata/mydb/redo1_b3.rdo') SIZE 20M
USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY "Welcome3" USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY "Welcome3";
```

Please help

Comment: How have you created the Database? Using DBCA or SQLPLUS or any other?

Comment: What is the history of this database - has it ever worked, or have you just created it? If so, how - new build through dbca, cloning, something else? Did the control files use to exist and now they're missing? Or do they exist with different names (`ctrl<SID>.dbf`, say)?

Comment: i am trying to create new database,,, using sqlplus

Comment: till now, i created .ora file and created database, trying to startup by using pfile to .ora created ... i dont see files in directory mentioned in command show parameter

Comment: So have successfully executed `CREATE DATABASE` command and now trying to start the database instance? Can you provide the `CREATE DATABASE` command?

Comment: @JSapkota yeah i successfully executed create database command.. now trying to start.. i dont see control files on location specified

Comment: adding db creation script in quiestion details

Comment: So have you just got the wrong control file names/paths in the pfile? Have you looked to see which files were actually created?

Comment: i put just name for controls in pfile, however i dont see them created , when database was created

Comment: i have resolved this, i think there were some whitespaces in .ora file i created.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the OP's solution (he had some extra whitespace in the wrong place in the init.ora file), I encountered the exact same errors about controlfiles when I attempted to set a "hidden" parameter`_disable_highres_ticks` to an apparently invalid value.